# Is Fineuploader with File Chunking more expensive on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Fineuploader http://fineuploader.com/ has the possibility to use File Chunking

> File Chunking / Partitioning
>
> Splitting a file into smaller pieces
>   allows for a more efficient overall upload, and powers some Fine
>   Uploader features such as pausing, and resuming uploads. Fine Uploader
>   can also upload multiple chunks for the same file concurrently.

Is Fineuploader with File Chunking more expensive on Amazon S3? Thinking of that Amazon will charge you for each request to Amazon S3. If fineuploader splits any file into smaller pieces it becomes more requests to Amazon = more expensive. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are more requests, so chunking may result in increased fees.  If you expect to allow your users to upload large files, the benefit of chunking is significant in terms of user experience, especially when the [new concurrent chunking feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/concurrent-chunking.html) is enabled.  However, if the increased cost bothers you, you can always turn chunking off.